# Install packages from a requiremets.txt file in a git repository

Tags: python, git, pip, requirements.txt

I have a github link 
https://github.com/xxxx/xxx/xx/master/requirements.txt.
I want to install all the packages from the above url to my local virtual environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just download the file, navigate to its directory, and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Doesn't matter. Yes, you can download it via `git fetch`, but you can also download it manually. Do as you prefer. `pip install -r` will simply install all requirements listed in the specified requirements textfile.